# Sets of discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis

I need help answering the two following self-study problems.

1. Let $F$ be a closed set. Construct a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the set of points where $f$ fails to be continuous is precisely $F$.
2. Consider the open set $O$. Construct a function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose discontinuous points is precisely $O$.

These are exercises on continuous functions, as given in Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis.*

For the first question, if $F$ is finite or countable, then it seems simple enough to define a function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \ \text{if} \ x \in F \\ 0 \ \text{if} \ x \not\in F \end{cases}$$ which is discontinuous at each point in $F$. I can see how such an approach might hold for any closed set with no interior points; however, I do not know how to proceed beyond this.

For the second question, a suggested approach is to make use of the continuous function  $h(x) = \inf \{ | x - a| : a \in F \}$, where $F$ is a non-empty closed set.

Comment: Is this homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1.: Let $g:\Bbb R\to [0,1]$ be continuous such that $g(x)=0$ when $x$ belongs to the closed set $\Bbb R$ \ $int (F)$ and $g(x)>0$ when $x\in int (F)$. Let $S$ be a dense, co-dense subset of $int(F).$ For example let $S=\Bbb Q\cap int(F).$  For $x\in int (F)$ let $f(x)=g(x)\chi_S(x).$ For $x\in F$ \ $int (F)$ let $f(x)=1$.For  $x\in \Bbb R$ \ $F$ let $f(x)=0.$

BTW. Any $A\subset \Bbb R$ is the set of points of continuity of some function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ iff $A$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set. Moreover, if $A$ is a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb R$ then there exists $f:\Bbb R\to [0,1]$ with $f(x)=0$ for $x\in A$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x\not \in A,$ and such that $f$ is continuous at each point of $A$ and at no point of $\Bbb R$ \ $A.$

Comment: For the trivial case of $F = \emptyset$, could we not make the ``vacuous" argument that every function continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ has no points of discontinuity and its points of discontinuity is $F$?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding what it means for "$f$ to fail to be continuous at a set of points"? I took it to mean $f$ is discontinuous at every $x \in F$. What if we consider the closed interval $F = [a, b]$? We still define the function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as  $g(x) = \inf \{ |x-a| : x \in F \}$ and take some $V \subset F^{c}$ and $W = F^{c} \cap V^{c}$ so that $V$ and $W$ are dense in $F^{c}$. Following your example, if $V = \mathbb{Q} \cap F^{c}$, then $f(x) = g(x) \chi_{V} (x) = 0$ for all $x \in F$. Does this not mean $f$ is continuous at all points in $F$?

Comment: It is  i who mis-read the Q and gave an $f$ that is continuous only on $F$. I will re-write it at once.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1.If your closed set is countable then take any contionus function and change it a little so that point discontinuity arise

Use dirichlet function on closed interval and constant function everywhere else .

Use this two piece of idea to create a function for general situation

2. Open sets in $R$ are open intervals.
   Create a function whose limit point is end points of open intervals but discontinuous on open interval